# How to compute the limit of a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

I would like to know if the following sequence :  $ T_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k^{2}} \delta_{\frac{1}{k}} $ converge in $ \mathcal{D} ' ( \mathbb{R} ) $. If it's converge in $ \mathcal{D} ' ( \mathbb{R} ) $, we must compute its limit.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ de a test function. Then
$$
T_n(\phi)=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{k^2}\,\phi\Bigl(\frac1k\Bigr).
$$
Since $\phi$ is bounded, the series is absolutely convergent, that is
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}T_n(\phi)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{k^2}\,\phi\Bigl(\frac1k\Bigr)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\,\phi\Bigl(\frac1k\Bigr).
$$
Define
$$
T(\phi)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\,\phi\Bigl(\frac1k\Bigr).
$$
Then $t$ is a distribution and $T_n$ converges to $T$ in the distribution sense.

Comment: Thanks. Is $T$ a distribution which its support is $ \{ \frac{1}{n} \ | \ n \geq 0 \} $. What is its support exactly ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Th support is $\{1/n:n\ge1\}\cup\{0\}$ (the support is a closed set.)